# Android Development: Simplest collision detection?

Tags: android, 2d, collision-detection

I'm trying to accomplish collision detection. Im not using OpenGl, I'm using canvas/surfaceview.

I have 2 bitmaps.
This is what ive come up to so far:

```
public boolean inBounds(int x2,int y2, int x,int y,int width,int height){
    if(x2 > x && x2 < x + width -1 && y2 > y && y2 < y + height -1){
        return true;
    }
     return false;

       }
```

This does run but it only detects collision if x2 and y2's corner is inside the other object.

So how do I improve my collision detection?

[image]

This image I found on the web should detect collision in my program.

//Simon

Answer (score 2):

If they are circles then here's a little pseudo code for you:

```
if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(bitmap1.centerX-bitmap2.centerX, 2) + Math.pow(bitmap1.centerY-bitmap2.centerY, 2))<=bitmap1.width) 
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Since you now want rectangles (and assuming they're different sizes):

```
if (Math.abs(bitmap1.centerX-bitmap2.centerX)<=(bitmap1.width+bitmap2.width)/2f
    && Math.abs(bitmap1.centerY-bitmap2.centerY)<=(bitmap1.height+bitmap2.height)/2f)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly. You may need to offset some things by 1 if you're pixel-perfect.

Comment: Thank you! Will try this as soon as possible(after some sleeep xD)

Comment: Shouldn't that || be a && ? since they only collide if it's on both axises.

Answer (score 1):

### To detect Rectangle Collission

```
bool isIntersect(Rectangle a, Rectangle b){
    return a.Left < b.Right && a.Top < b.Bottom &&
           b.Left < a.Right && b.Top < a.Bottom;
}
```

### For Two Circle Collission Detection

```
bool isIntersect(Circle a, Circle b)
{ 
Vector<ClassWithLengthRadiusProp> vDistanceProp = a.Center - b.Center;
    return vDistanceProp.Length < a.Radius + b.Radius;
}
```

### OR(Accurate With Sqrt)

```
bool isIntersect(Circle a, Circle b)
{
   Vector<ClassWithLengthRadiusProp> vDistanceProp = a.Center - b.Center;
    float radiusSum = a.Radius + b.Radius;
    float squaredDistanceLength = vDistanceProp .x * vDistanceProp .x +
                                  vDistanceProp .y * vDistanceProp .y;

    return squaredDistanceLength < radiusSum * radiusSum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(r1.lowerLeft.x < r2.lowerLeft.x + r2.width 
   && r1.lowerLeft.x + r1.width > r2.lowerLeft.x 
   && r1.lowerLeft.y < r2.lowerLeft.y + r2.height 
   && r1.lowerLeft.y + r1.height > r2.lowerLeft.y)
   return true;

   else
   return false;
```

That should do it unless you want to do a circle collision detection. r1 & r2 and defined as Rects

Answer (score 0):

The [android.graphics.Rect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) class contains some nice functions to do this in one line. You can check out intersect.